# Ajax form submittal, how to get this to work

Tags: ajax, jquery

Help, I'm trying to get a form to submit - ajax style.

Essentially, I would like to be able to "submit" the form to another page, without redirecting the user to the second page.  Ideally it would show some sort of "success" or "failure" message on the forms page.

The code below is not working.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

I've tested my process.php by posting and redirecting the user to the page and it works flawlessly.  Any advice on what I can do to get this to work with ajax?  (I'm using jquery)

```
<script>
    $(function() { // wait for the DOM to be ready
    $('#personal_email').submit(function() { // bind function to submit event of form
       $.ajax({
          type: $(this).attr('method'), // get type of request from 'method'
          url: $(this).attr('action'), // get url of request from 'action'
          data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize the form's data
          success: function(responseText) {
              // if everything goes well, update the div with the response
              $('#result').html(responseText);
          }
      });
    return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
    });
   });
</script>
```

....

```
<form  name="personal_email" id="personal_email" action="proccess.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
     <input type="text" id="newsletteremail" name="newsletteremail" value="my email address" onfocus="if(this.value=='my email address')this.value=''"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
   </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // wait for the DOM to be ready
    $('#personal_email').submit(function() { // bind function to submit event of form
       $.ajax({
          type: $(this).attr('method'), // get type of request from 'method'
          url: $(this).attr('action'), // get url of request from 'action'
          data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize the form's data
          success: function(responseText) {
              // if everything goes well, update the div with the response
              $('#result').html(responseText);
          }
      });
    return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
    });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<form  name="personal_email" id="personal_email" action="process.php" method="post">
 <fieldset>
     <input type="text" id="newsletteremail" name="newsletteremail" value="my email address" onfocus="if(this.value=='my email address')this.value=''"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
   </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping that the functionality would be that the "Thanks" replaces the form...  This currently does not do that.

Comment: You hava not specified that in the question description. Anyway, how can you accomplish that if you try to replace an element with id "result" with the response text? There is no element with id "result" in your code.